# How to setup output path to compiled css files using `vscode live sass compiler extension` in windows10?

Tags: sass, visual-studio-code

I failed to run `node-sass`(node module), where I was able to setup path for input `extensions.scss` files and output files generated after compiling to `dist/` folder.

Now, I am using vscode extension `live sass compiler`,

at bottom bar, when I clicked `Watched Sass` then it compiled automatically `scss` file to `css` but in same folder.

`main.scss` is compiled to `main.css`.

[image]

problem is that I wanted to create that `compiled css` file in other folder .i.e. in output folder `./dist/`.

I have manually created `main.css` file in `./dist/folder`.

How can I setup path to source and destination files in that extension?

Comment: There might be a setting inside your User Settings. Try opening the Command Palette and searching for "args".

Comment: there are only settings related to terminal, when I searched "args" in ` `file>preference>settings>user Settings`.

Comment: Live Sass Compiler settings doc here: https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-sass-compiler/blob/master/docs/settings.md

Answer (score 55):

I have had the same issue when I started implementing SMACSS methodology to my projects. This is the solution I have tried. hope it will help you.

[image]

Go to VScode User Settings --> Select "Live Sass Compiler Config --> add

```
"liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [{
        "format": "expanded",
        "extensionName": ".css",
        "savePath": "./css"
    }]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Suraj for restructuring my answer. Btw I'm very new to Stackoverflow

Comment: Thanks. But for me, I had to go to File/Preferences/Settings then Extensions/Live Sass Compiler.  I then clicked on 'Edit in settings.json' and added the settings suggested at the end.  But any route to 'settings.json' will do.

Comment: Is it possible to change the output path for `.css.map` files? My problem is that I want the `.scss` and `.css.map` to be in the same folder and save the `.css` only on the output folder.

Comment: How do u get to user settings?

Comment: This works fine but is there a way to do this differently for different projects (settings file in project folder)?

Answer (score 26):

Go to VScode menu- file>preferences>settings>extension>live sass copile config>edit in settings.json

and paste it code >>

```
  "liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
    {
      "format": "expanded",
      "extensionName": ".css",
      "savePath": "~/../css/"
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 8):

You can go to VSCode Setting.json file and add following lines after the existing configuration.

Example:

```
"liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
    {
      "format": "expanded",
      "extensionName": ".css",
      "savePath": "~/../dist/css/"
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 6):

Open your vs.code and go to settings then search `Sass` and see below `Live Sass Compiler` click here and see right side  `Live Sass Compile > Settings: Formats` then edit this Settings and change only your `SavePath` Like example below this code.

```
{
  "scss.format.enable": true,
  "liveSassCompile.settings.autoprefix": [


  ],
  "liveSassCompile.settings.watchOnLaunch": false,
  "liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [

    {
        "format": "expanded",
        "extensionName": ".css",
        "savePath": "/assets/css", // you can change this path
        "savePathReplacementPairs": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this will help anyone since it's been a long time it was posted but I had multiple folders opened in VSCode recently and everytime I tried to use live sass compiler it would go to the folder that was on top of the list and create the css/styles.css file(s) inside that directory.

I saw this solution on the Live Sass Compiler creators website:
https://ritwickdey.github.io/vscode-live-sass-compiler/docs/faqs.html

What you do is simple, lets say you have a folder architecture
[like my one here. (image link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpZbn.png)

All you have to do is make a folder named .vscode and add a settings.json file inside that folder.

Inside settings.json paste the following code:

```
{
"liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
    {
        "format": "expanded",
        "extensionName": ".css",
        "savePath": "/Parallax/css"
    },
    {
        "extensionName": ".min.css",
        "format": "compressed",
        "savePath": "/Parallax/dist/css"
    }
],

"liveSassCompile.settings.excludeList": [
    "**/node_modules/**",
    ".vscode/**"
],
"liveSassCompile.settings.generateMap": true,
"liveSassCompile.settings.autoprefix": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
]
```

}

Notice how my `liveSassCompile.settings.formats` is formatted: I've written the save paths as /Parallax/css/ and /Parallax/dist/css. This goes to the project root and saves the css files inside the folders called css and dist which are inside the [Parallax directory. (image link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXudD.png)

In conclusion each time you want to change the save path all you have to do is modify the `settings.json` file inside the `.vscode` folder rather than modifying the user settings which is tedious in my opinion.

Final structure should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqXmP.png) once you edited the `main.scss` file.

Answer (score 3):

Go to live SassCompiler extension settings and enter below code setting in JSON file and save.

```
    "liveSassCompile.settings.autoprefix": [],
"liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
    {
        "format": "expanded",
        "extensionName": ".css",
        "savePath": "~/../dist/css/"
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Inside your Project Create a (.vscode) Directory. In the .vscode folder create a json file named settings.json. Inside of the settings.json, type the following key-value pairs. By the way you'll get intelli-sense. I hope this will work

```
{
 "liveSassCompile.settings.formats":[
    {
        "format": "expanded",
        "extensionName": ".css",
        "savePath": "/css"
    },
    {
        "extensionName": ".min.css",
        "format": "compressed",
        "savePath": "/dist/css"
    }
],
"liveSassCompile.settings.excludeList": [
   "**/node_modules/**",
   ".vscode/**"
],
"liveSassCompile.settings.generateMap": true,
"liveSassCompile.settings.autoprefix": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

None of above methods worked for me until I used the code below in the settings.json.

```
    {

"liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
  {
    "format": "expanded",
    "extensionName": ".css",
    "savePath": "~/../../css/"     
}

],

  "editor.minimap.enabled": true,
  "liveSassCompile.settings.generateMap": false
}
```

> On the savePath line  you have to keep the "~" or else it wont work.
>
> On "editor.minimap.enabled":  and "liveSassCompile.settings.generateMap":
>
> These lines are for if you want to generate a map.css file, put "false" for no, or "true" for yes.

Comment: okay, might have to check that, implemented it long back, will have to check again @myko.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to generate `.css` files in a `css` folder in the project root directory:

```
"liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
    {
      "format": "expanded",
      "extensionName": ".css",
      "savePath": "/css"
    }
  ],
```

Or to generate in `dist/css`:

```
"liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
    {
      "format": "expanded",
      "extensionName": ".css",
      "savePath": "/dist/css"
    }
  ]
```

This can either be in VS Code global `settings.json` to apply to all projects (look for `"liveSassCompile.settings.formats"` and change the `"savePath"` line; the provided `"format"` and `"extensionName"` are already the defaults), or if you want to limit the settings to the current project, place the settings in a `settings.json` file within a folder named `.vscode`.

Refer to the Live Sass Compiler settings doc for more information: https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-sass-compiler/blob/master/docs/settings.md

Answer (score 1):

Do everything as Sulara said. When you open the settings.json file, it may look like this.

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": 0
}
```

So, you need to apply the recommended settings like the following.

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [{
        "format": "expanded",
        "extensionName": ".css",
        "savePath": "./css"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]I have the same issue but this was able to help, Just replace the `setting.json` of the extension with this if you want the folder to be created in the directory with your Sass folder

```
{
  "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
  "tabnine.experimentalAutoImports": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
  "workbench.colorTheme": "SynthWave '84",
  "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
  "liveSassCompile.settings.autoprefix": [],
  "liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
    {
      "format": "expanded",
      "extensionName": ".css",
      "savePath": "~/../css/"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go to VSCode Setting.json file and add following lines after the existing configuration.

Example:

src path- project_folder/sass/style.scss

output path - project_folder/css/style.css

`"liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [{
        "format": "expanded",
        "extensionName": ".css",
        "savePath": "/css/"
    }]`

Answer (score 0):

settings > extensions > live sass compiler > show output window on

Set the setting to warning or error. You could also use none if you want

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a23gs.png)